# How to build kernel-debuginfo from available kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-debugging

Problem: I have kernel(with iso) however that iso is not having kernel-debuginfo, I want to build build kernel-debuginfo to debug kernel issues. Any references will be appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific. What problem are you attempting to debug? OS distro and version (sounds like EL)? What patch or config are you attempting to apply? Is there a relevant kernel in the test repo or build system?

Comment: I have only iso without debuginfo and want to build kernel-debuginfo for it for future kernel issues. Kernel is not from upstream it is custom build but without debuginfo.